# logcat filled with java.io.IOException: Connection refused messages

Tags: java, android, logcat, android-logcat

My logcat is filled with following message -

```
E/UsDebuggingManager(  476): java.io.IOException: Connection refused
E/UsDebuggingManager(  476):    at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.connectLocal(Native Method)
E/UsDebuggingManager(  476):    at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.connect(LocalSocketImpl.java:287)
E/UsDebuggingManager(  476):    at android.net.LocalSocket.connect(LocalSocket.java:130)
E/UsDebuggingManager(  476):    at com.android.server.DebuggingService.listenToSocket(UsDebuggingManager.java:75)
E/UsDebuggingManager(  476):    at com.android.server.DebuggingService.run(UsDebuggingManager.java:111)
E/UsDebuggingManager(  476):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I looked at `UsbDebuggingManager. java` and can see that a thread is trying to connect to adb server and the connection is failing. I am not getting any other messages apart from this.

Any help to resolve this issue is appreciated.

@MHP: I get this error as soon as I start logcat and it keeps coming. No app is running.

Comment: please explain your question.when got error,in which class,...

Comment: This is probably the kind of minor issue with the device software (rather than your app) which you ignore, not resolve.  Does the process id number in () even match that of your app during the same run?  Are there distinct problems in your app which you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Chris: These messages come even when there is no app running. I looked at the UsbDebuggingManager.java and saw that thread created in this service, is trying to connect adb socket but its failing with this log. If you can throw some light on fixing it, will be very helpful.

Comment: If they come without any app running (be careful with that term on Android), then there is little you can do but ignore them, switch devices, or hack your device and install a custom ROM.  Despite "looking bad" do you have any evidence that there is an actual functionality problem related to these messages?

Comment: I dont see any functionality issues as of now, but its flooding the logcat and making it very difficult to find appropriate debug messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happened to me as well. I rooted my android device (a Shield Tegra) and I installed [adbd Insecure](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.adbd) to have `adbd root priviliges` on it.

What I did is disabling this option:

- **Enable insecure adbd**

[image]

I don't know if you did the same, but disabling "enable insecure adbd" fixed all the `java.io.IOException: Connection refused errors`.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This is probably cause of your phone. Please uninstall any avast services if running. Also did you rooted or changed internal space of your phone by some hack?
Check if same works with other phone or not